# Rails: Can't access parent id in controller create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that I've been working on. I have set up Users, Catalogues and Products.

Users have many Catalogues.
Catalogues have many Products.

In the Products controller, I'm attempting to create a product. This is the function I currently have:

```
def create
  @product = @catalogue.products.build(params[:product])

  if @product.save
    flash[:success] = "Product created!"
    redirect_to @catalogue
  else
    flash[:error] = "Save error: Product not created."
    render 'static_pages/home'
  end
end
```

I have a function that sets the @catalogue using a before_filter:

```
  def get_catalogue 
    @catalogue = Catalogue.find_by_id(:catalogue_id)
  end
```

This function doesn't appear to be working as the error I'm getting is:

NoMethodError in ProductsController#create

undefined method `products' for nil:NilClass

I assumed that the products catalogue_id would be set after the new action was performed.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Sidenote: You can debug incoming params with `raise params.inspect` and `raise params.to_yaml` anywhere in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in the `before_filter`. I think it should use `params[:catalogue_id]` and not a symbol.

```
def get_catalogue 
  @catalogue = Catalogue.find_by_id(params[:catalogue_id])
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply. I tried your suggestion but I appear to be getting the same error still.

Comment: What does your server receive as `params`?

Comment: I'm not too sure how to answer really. I'm a beginner at this. I have a catalogue being displayed on http://localhost:3000/catalogues/1. And I have a button there that links to the 'newproduct' link. This is set up to be matched like so: match '/newproduct/', to: 'products#new'

Comment: The problem is, you need to pass catalogue_id to your controller. This would mean to access `localhost:3000/newproduct?catalogue_id=1` from your browser. Then you get this `1` as `params[:catalogue_id]`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use nested routing?

> resources :catalogues do
>
> > resources :products
>
> end

Then you can use

> catalogue_products_path(@catalogue)

which will give access to params[:catalogue_id] to you in the controller.